# search the text and replace the text in the html to highlight the searched word in angular

Tags: html, angular, innerhtml, highlight, innertext

When I try to search for a text and update the text I am facing an issue.

```
<span class="container">this is a container</span>
```

i used document.getElementByClassname to get the element and when i replace the container with `<mark>container</mark>`

```
<span class="<mark>container</mark>">this is a <mark>container</mark></span>
```

replacement happens even inside the element class name but I need this only to happen at

```
<span class="container">this is a <mark>container</mark></span>
```

I used regex to find the searched values but it also found inside the tag element

I tried updating the innerText but that corrupts the HTML document

Does anyone know how this can be achieved?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a long search and understanding the regex I found out the solution via regex

(?<!<[^>]*)container(?<![^>]*<)

this is a container

the above regex matches only the container outside the HTML tags can be testes using the regex tester online http://regexstorm.net/